# Print image field path in views-view-fields--key-projects.html.twig

Tags: views, theming, media

I am working with Drupal 8 and trying to print some fields through a twig file.

Created:

1. A view (format:grid)
2. A content type (fields: title, body image)
3. Contents

File working on:

1. views-view-fields--[machine-name].html.twig

To Do:

1. How can I print the path of the image in the content?
2. How can I print the path of the node/content on a Read More link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the path of an image in a view, use the image format 'URL to Image' in the field setup. I have not found a really good way to get the site absolute, rather than relative url, but prefixing the returned value in a rewrite block with `{{ url'(<front>') }}` is almost there:

```
{{ url'(<front>') }}{{ field_image }}
```

To use that in a different field (content), mark it 'Excluded from display' and then reference that field using a rewrite in another field, or using a twig field template.

Answer (score 0):

Q: How can I print the path of the image in the content?
A: I got the file path of image by printing the image field directly in twig.
Like: {{ fields.field_sliding_image.content }}

Q: How can I print the path of the node/content on a Read More link?
A: I added a path field in my view and then in twig I did the following:
Like: {{ fields.path.content }}